# Display Different Windows Within a Panel in a Form (Windows Forms Application)

Tags: c#, winforms

I am working through an Algorithm book (C#) and am consolidating all of the examples and algorithms into a windows form app.  The idea is to have a side menu with buttons to choose which "program" you want to run and to the right of the menu with the buttons the Panel will display the form or user control created for that specific algorithm.  For example one of the menu options will be "Area of Parallelogram" when clicked the User Control will show to the right of the selection menu (within a Panel) with the input boxes for height and width, a button to calculate it and an output Textbox for the results.  I am kind of stuck on which approach I should use, I tried using multiple Panels layered on top of each other and hide them initially then do a Show() on-click but this proved extremely problematic.  I read that using User Controls would allow for better control but am unsure how to proceed.  I guess my question is how do I have the User Control display inside the Panel within my Form which displays the programs?  I would upload a pic but I do not have the rep.

Comment: To inherit you just do a ":" after the class name so yours would be myclass:Panel

Comment: @Trey Thanks for the reply, "inherit" was a poor choice of words on my part, I meant how do I display the specific User Control within the Panel?

Comment: For each user control which you want to show, create instance of the user control and add it to `Controls` collection of the `Panel`. What's the problem?

Comment: @RezaAghaei I knew I was missing something small.  Thank you.

Comment: What I would do is run menu options through switch case and show/hide panels accordingly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rather than instantiate the controls for each application, hide them all, and just show the ones from the selected "application", consider this: design your main selector panel as a placeholder. When the user selects an application, assign the application panel instance in place of the selector panel instance and allow the application to execute to completion. After it exits, restore the placeholder instance.

Comment: Thanks, I think you have set me on the right path I will let you know (:

Answer (score 0):

Bind all the button click event to `button1_Click`.

Place your panels on top of each other and change the visible properties to false.

Then, use `switch-case` as below.

```
Button btn = sender as Button;
switch (btn.Text)
{
    case "Triangle":
        pnlCircle.Visible = false;
        pnlSquare.Visible = false;
        pnlTriangle.Visible = true;
        break;

    case "Square":
        pnlCircle.Visible = false;
        pnlSquare.Visible = true;
        pnlTriangle.Visible = false;
        break;

    case "Circle":
        pnlCircle.Visible = true;
        pnlSquare.Visible = false;
        pnlTriangle.Visible = false;
        break;
}
```